# remount Linux root partition after accidently disconnected

Tags: linux

I have a bootable USB Linux. Occasionally, someone will disconnect the USB power and bash would complain any command was not found. Even if I reconnect the drive, dmesg said the drive has been detected, all the commands were still unusable. Any way to remount the root partition without reboot?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the `remount` option: `mount -o remount`, which is also used to e.g. make a read-write filesystem read-only (remount it read-only). This should force `mount` to renew the connection. For details, just take a look at `man mount`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure if mount command is available after this catastrophic event happen. I'll try it out next time when this happens.

Comment: Indeed, this does not work for me when the pen drive is pulled out and plugged back in.  I get a bunch of "command not found" error messages when I try to `sudo mount -o remount /`

Comment: @JoeyAdams behaviours differs with e.g. different file systems and other conditions. I remember e.g. broken Samba shares where a hard case, as sometimes the system won't let go of the "old mounts" (the broken ones), and thus you could not renew them. I have no "100% sure" solution, sorry -- which is why I wrote "You could try". Sometimes it does work, other times it does not...